# I am getting an internal error that prevents update manager from opening, pkg unidentified

Tags: 12.04

Error message says that the package can not be identified, update manager will not load to see if there are any known bugs on this.  I am on 12.04 running on a Dell Laptop.  Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, then post error messages. Open a terminal window, and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install package_name
```

where `package_name` is the name of the package you are trying to install.